# How to join on Mysql multiple tables and result 4 column record

Tags: mysql, join

How to mysql join on multiple tables and result 5 column record like below the image.
(I have two separate credit table and debit table)

http://www.pcnbd.com/express-holiday/public/debit_credit.php

I create this code :

```
SELECT  `payDate`.`date`, `sPay`.`total_payment` as STot, `bPay`.`total_payment` as BTot
FROM ( SELECT `sale_payment`.`payment_date` as `date` FROM `sale_payme         
UNION all
SELECT `buy_payment`.`payment_date`  as `date`  FROM `buy_payment`
                ) payDate            
left  JOIN sale_payment  sPay
ON  `payDate`.`date` = `sPay`.`payment_date`
left  JOIN buy_payment  bPay
ON  `payDate`.`date` = `bPay`.`payment_date`
```

OUTPUT This result :

http://www.pcnbd.com/express-holiday/public/debit_credit.php

I need *Sale* and *Buy* table All row together - matching by date , but here buy and sale table row return duplicate row,

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

TRY TO USE UNION ONLY RATHER THAT UNION ALL. BECAUSE UNION ALL RERTURNS ALL THE DATA WHILE UNION RETURNS ONLY THE MATHCING DATA OF 2 TABLES.